# Can item spawn with over cap hero/tower stats?

Tags: pc, dungeon-defenders

The cap for upgrading a hero/tower stat on an item is 420 but can an item spawn with higher stats or is that an indication that it is a hacked item?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but I think the cap was raised again after the introduction of Transcendent items in the second Shards DLC.

Comment: its crazy power creep like this that made me stop playing the game :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they can naturally drop with higher-than-cap stats. It depends on item quality:

- Mythical: Normal cap is 360 but can drop with stats up to 400
- Transcendent: Normal cap is 420 but can drop with stats up to 500
- Supreme: Normal cap is 500 but can drop with stats up to 600

Generally you will only see these items on higher-end survival maps, as the loot quality must be extremely high in order for items to get that high of stats.